# problem knowing the data of a particular camera

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a practice simple app as I am learning swiftUI. My current problem seems to lie in this function:

variables

```
@State var cameras: [Camera] = []
@State var angle: Double = 0.0


func fetchAngle(){
    COLLECTION_CAMERAS.whereField("active", isEqualTo: true).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, _ in
        self.cameras = snapshot!.documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Camera.self)})
        self.angle = cameras[0].angle
        
}
```

There can only be one active camera out of the three.

I know its bad practice but all the program is in the MainView() for simplicity, after I finish debugging I will use MVVM.

The `angle` variable is `@Published`, because I want to redraw the user interface when its updated.

The there is a set of 3 buttons and each time I press one of them, successfully update in firebase the active field to true or false.

As there are three cameras I fetch the collection and wish to only get the camera where the active field is true. So far so good, my problem starts (I think) with this code self.angle = cameras[0].angle. What I wish to achieve is to be able to set self.angle with the angle of the only camera that has active == true.

Comment: `self.angle = cameras.first(where: { $0.active == true })?.angle`?

Comment: It's not clear why cameras are being stored in an array since there is only ever one camera active - you can just store the camera. Also, there's no need to compactMap either since well, there's only one camera. From there, what's the actual issue - is the code crashing? Did you add a breakpoint and step through the code, inspecting the vars along the way to determine what line is not working as expected? Please update the question with details and we'll take a look.